# Discord.py Ticket Create something is Wrong

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey guys Here i have a Code like, Sometime if i Create a Ticket the Perms dont get edited like everyone can see the Ticket

Can someone please help out? :D

The only thing thast is wrong is the Perms thing like i said it sometimes dont edits the Code

Would be Amazing if you can help its very Important for our Server and we need some Help

If you can Please edit the code i really dont know what is wrong with this Code would

Have a Good time and thanks for Helping :D

```
@bot.command()
async def new(ctx, *, args = None):

    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    if args == None:
        message_content = ""

    else:
        message_content = "".join(args)

    with open("data.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    ticket_number = int(data["ticket-counter"])
    ticket_number += 1

    ticket_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("ticket-{}".format(ticket_number))
    await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.get_role(ctx.guild.id), send_messages=False, read_messages=False)

    for role_id in data["valid-roles"]:
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)

        await ticket_channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)

    await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title="Ticket by {}#{}".format(ctx.author.name, ctx.author.discriminator), description= "Hey i have a Build in responding system Ask things and Maybe i can respond, if not our Supporters can help you out!\n``To close this ticket type +close``", color=0x00a8ff)

    await ticket_channel.send(embed=em)

    pinged_msg_content = ""
    non_mentionable_roles = []

    if data["pinged-roles"] != []:

        for role_id in data["pinged-roles"]:
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)

            pinged_msg_content += role.mention
            pinged_msg_content += " "

            if role.mentionable:
                pass
            else:
                await role.edit(mentionable=True)
                non_mentionable_roles.append(role)

        await ticket_channel.send(pinged_msg_content)

        for role in non_mentionable_roles:
            await role.edit(mentionable=False)

    data["ticket-channel-ids"].append(ticket_channel.id)

    data["ticket-counter"] = int(ticket_number)
    with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

    created_em = discord.Embed(title="Clipox Support", description="Ohh... a Wild Ticket appeared, Look here {}".format(ticket_channel.mention), color=0x00a8ff)

    await ctx.send(embed=created_em)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone role, use `ctx.guild.default_role`

Change this line

```py
await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.get_role(ctx.guild.id), send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
```

to this

```py
await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
```